# Worksheets copy not works

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have a spreadsheet named "BalançoGeral.xlsm" that opens another spreasheet named "ControleFinanceiroGeral.xlsm" and I would like to copy the sheet (4) of the opened spreadsheet after the first sheet from "BalançoGeral.xlsm".
The following copy command does not work and the sequence does not issue any error message.
What is the problem?

Vitor

*Workbooks.Open Filename:="ControleFinanceiroGeral.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True
Workbooks("ControleFinanceiroGeral.xlsm").Worksheets(4).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)*

Comment: Hi Vitor, welcome to StackOverflow! To make it easier for others to answer your question, please include some additional context and tags: It might especially help to include the programming language you are using.

Comment: Thanks Friedrich. I did it just now.